# Is $ H\left\{x_h(t)\right\} = H\left\{x\left(t-\frac{\pi}{2w_c}\right)\right\} $ where $H$ is Hilbert transform

Tags: hilbert-transform

Accordind to my understanding of the following:

[image] 
[image]

$$H\left\{X(f)\right\} = -j\;sgn(f)\; X(f)  \qquad(1)$$

my work so far:

since $ x_h(t) = x\left(t-\frac{\pi}{2w_c}\right)$, Their Hilbert transforms are equal in time and frequency domains.Hence,

$$ H\left\{x_h(t)\right\} = H\left\{x\left(t-\frac{\pi}{2w_c}\right)\right\}, \:\text{where $H$ is Hilbert transform. 
} $$

Let  $ \: y(t) = x\left(t-\frac{\pi}{2w_c}\right)\ \: $.We have

$$ H\left\{x_h(t)\right\} = H\left\{y(t)\right\} .$$ Therefore,

$$H\left\{X_h(f)\right\} = H\left\{Y(f)\right\} \\ \\ $$

L.H.S

by applying what is stated in the picure, we have:
$$H\left\{X_h(f)\right\} = -j\;sgn(f)\;  X_h(f)   = -j\;sgn(f)\;  \left[-j \; X(f) \; sgn(f)\right] $$

after simplification:
$$\text {L.H.S} = -X(f)$$

R.H.S
$$H\left\{Y(f)\right\} = -j\;sgn(f)\; Y(f) = -j\;sgn(f)\; \left[X(f) \; e^{-j2\pi \left(\frac{f}{4f_c}\right)} \right ] = \text {R.H.S} $$  by simplifying $$ \frac{\pi}{2w_c} = \frac{\pi}{2\left[2\pi f_c\right]}  = \frac{1}{4fc} $$ and by the shifting property:

$$F \left\{x(t-t_0)\right\} = X(f) \; e^{-j 2\pi f t_0}  \\ \\ $$

$$ - X(f) \quad \ne  \quad -j\;sgn(f)\; \left[X(f) \; e^{-j2\pi \left(\frac{f}{4f_c}\right)} \right ] $$

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite unclear what you're actually asking, and most of your equations have no meaning. But one thing that you need to understand is that the equation

$$\mathcal{H}\{x(t)\}=x\left(t-t_0\right),\qquad t_0=\frac{\pi}{2\omega_0}=\frac{1}{4f_0}\tag{1}$$

only makes sense for sinusoidal functions $x(t)$ (of frequency $f_0$). For non-sinusoidal signals $x(t)$ the Hilbert transform of $x(t)$ can only be written as an integral:

$$\mathcal{H}\{x(t)\}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x(\tau)}{t-\tau}d\tau\tag{2}$$

where the improper integral is interpreted as the Cauchy principal value. In general, the Hilbert transform is not just a simple time shift.

For a sinusoidal signal $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0t+\phi)$ you can indeed show that the Hilbert transform corresponds to a delay of $t_0=1/(4f_0)$, i.e., in the frequency domain the following holds:

$$-j\,\textrm{sgn}(t)\,X(f)=X(f)e^{-j2\pi f t_0}=X(f)e^{-j\frac{\pi f}{2f_0}}\tag{3}$$